# Want to create autocomplete Search using stored procedure in ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework application

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have created a phonebook application using a database-first approach. And in that, I have to create an autocomplete feature. I have database with stored procedure written. I have also written JavaScript code for autocomplete.

My problem is, how to call stored procedure in controller.

My stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PhoneBook_SearchCustomers]
     @FName NVARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM UserDetails
    WHERE FName LIKE '%' + @FName + '%'
END
```

My `.cshtml` code is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#txtCustomer").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Home/AutoComplete/',
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",

                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return item;
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("#hfCustomer").val(i.item.val);
                },
                minLength: 1
            });
        });
    </script>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <input type="text" id="txtCustomer" name="CustomerName" />

    }
```

This is controller where i got stuck. No idea how to call stored procedure over to make autocomplete feature functional.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AutoComplete(string prefix)
{
    using (PhoneBookDatabaseEntities entities = new PhoneBookDatabaseEntities())
    {
        var nam = entities.PhoneBook_SearchCustomers(prefix);

        var customers = (from customer in nam
                         where customer.FName.StartsWith(prefix)
                         select new
                                 {
                                     label = customer.FName,
                                 }).ToList();
        return Json(customers);
    }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `.ToList()` at end of statement `var nam = entities.PhoneBook_SearchCustomers(prefix);` like

`var nam = entities.PhoneBook_SearchCustomers(prefix).ToList();`

If this doesn't resolve your problem then please provide more details(error if any).

Comment: I am getting the value in nam variable but there is no value in customers variable. Please guide me. There is something wrong into this code.                                   
                        var customers = (from customer in nam
                         where customer.FName.StartsWith(prefix)
                         select new
                                 {
                                     label = customer.FName,
                                 }).ToList();

Comment: This might be the reason that you are filtering `FName` in your SP by Contains() condition but in your code you are again filtering `FName` by StartsWith() condition. Suppose you have record in your DB whose `FName` is _Alex_ and value of `prefix = "lex"`. Your SP will return all those records whose `FName` is _Alex_ but in code those records will not added in `customers` variable because they don't start with `prefix = "lex"`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

From your Controller, look like you are using Entity Framework, so just call this for Stored Procedure:

`entities.SqlQuery<YourEntityType>("storedProcedureName",params);`

Long answer:

From your SP, can say that each time end user key in data, there will be a request send back to query database.

First, it depends on how you handling your auto complete box, is this a drop down appeared every time user key in a character?

If yes, every character key in, there is a query send back to SQL DB, which may causing performance issue.

If no, do you design a button that user need to click "Search", anytime they key in?

A suggestion, is passing the whole list with parameters, to front-end, and using 
is using third party JS library like [select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage), to handle it.

A good example can be found here: [Select2 - The Ultimate jQuery Autocomplete](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/623566/Select2-The-Ultimate-jQuery-Autocomplete)